# Synonyms for "just as how" or "similar to how"

Tags: synonyms

Is there a synonym for "just as how" or "similar to how"?

For instance, in the sentence,

> **Just as how** crabs can live in water, they can also live on land.

or

> **Similar to how** crabs can live in water, they can also live on land.

The above sentences are meant to be an example. I know there are many different ways to phrase it, but I'm specifically looking for a synonym for "just as how" and "Similar to how".

Thanks in advance

Comment: _How_ is not used as a relative pronoun any more. Instead, _that_ or `Zero` is used. Since a manner adverb can't be the subject, it can always be deleted as a relative pronoun, and that process has gone to completion with _how_. It's almost there with _why_, which can only appear as a relative pronoun in clauses modifying the noun _reason_. If you're looking for a free-relative substitute for **similar to how `S`*, try _similar to the way (that) `S`_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"While" is a good word to indicate a contradiction in thought.

> While crabs can live in water, they can also live on land.

Answer (score 1):

"Even as" sounds about right to my mid-western ears.